# Sci-Fi book from late 80s early 90s with humans being hunted on a different planet to Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm a bit sketchy on this one but will try and give as much detail as I can remember.

The story is about a group of humans who are on a planet other than Earth. They are being hunted by some kind of robots or artificial life form. The humans have exoskeleton legs to help them run faster. The robots hunting them use human body parts in their tech and also make sculptures/art works from human body parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Great Sky River (1987) by Gregory Benford

From Wikipedia:-

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Sky_River_(novel)

> Great Sky River tells the story of the Bishop family, who fight for their very existence on the planet Snowglade, which has been taken over by the Mechs. The Bishops are one of a number of families on Snowglade, all named for chess pieces. These "families" are more like clans or tribes. All use cybernetic implants and mechanical aids to enhance their perceptions and physical abilities.
>
> Personalities of dead members of the Family can be stored in memory tabs and accessed by plugging them into ports implanted in the neck. Bodily functions, such as the sexual drive, can be turned off to remove distractions. The Families seem to be equipped for long conflicts and periods of privation, continually migrating to avoid the Mechs.
>
> The novel takes place during a period when the Mechs have invaded Snowglade and are slowly altering its climate to suit themselves; drying it out to protect their steel bodies from rust. This adversely affects the humans, who otherwise seem to exist in a wary truce with the Mechs

Comment: That's it! Thanks!